# attempting to open a GET page from an angularjs scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I am attempting to call a get method to open a page in an angularjs scope. The get method is defined in a spring controller. The get method is called successfuly but the page never loads. Below is the snippet

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
                    if (response.status == 204) {

                    } else if (response.status == 200) {
                        $scope.nredit = {

                        };
                        $scope.goToView.goToView(); //call the get method here
                    }
```

here is the scope that calls the GET method but the page never opens

```
$scope.goToView = {
                goToView: function () {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/mypage',
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        if (response.status == 400) {
                            alert('Not allowed to view this page!');
                        } else if (response.status == 200) {
                           // $scope.users = response.data;
                        }
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    });
                }

            }
```

here is the get method controller defined in spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mypage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView goToView(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession userSession) throws IOException {  
        model.setViewName("view");
        return model;
    }
```

why is the view not opening/loading when called from angular

Comment: `// $scope.users = response.data;` — That's commented out. Why do you expect the page to load? You're doing nothing with the response.

Comment: the page does not need any data that is why it is commented out. meanwhile, the url is a get request that opens a page from the controller. Please post an answer instead

Comment: Do you mean "It opens a page from the controller if I type it into the address bar?". Because you aren't typing it into the address bar. You're making an Ajax request (the **entire** point of making an Ajax request is that it **doesn't** navigate the viewport to that URL).

Answer (score 0):

From the AngularJS docs:

> The $http service is a core AngularJS service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP.

In short: With $http you are doing an AJAX request. So this will return you the contents of target page (/mypage) in `response.data`. This does not trigger an redirect.

You should use AngularJS routing. You can find an example in this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: If you use [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io)  then you can [$state.go('somestate')](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#go). Or you can use `$window.location.href  = "/somepage";` which is the same as the normal `window.location.href`. But often it's out of the scope for a single page app to redirect to another page (leave the app/reload the app). Instead use states (fake pages) or change content with ajax-requests. You can still change the location in the address bar without going to a new page. This is normal for SPA's (and the router's job).

Answer (score 0):

You can make goToView available to the scope... it's kind of overkill to have a scoped object with a function in it. You should chain the promise for better readability.

Replace the success handler form initial promise with `handleResponse`, you're not showing the response so it's to tell what's going on.

```
let getPage = () => {
     return $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: '/mypage',
    });
}

let goToPage = (response) => {
    if (response.status == 400) {
         alert('Not allowed to view this page!');
    } else if (response.status == 200) {
         $scope.users = response.data;
    }
};

let handleResponse = (response) {
    ... dowhater
   return $scope.goToView();
}

$scope.goToView = () => {
   return getPage()
      .then(goToPage)
}
```

I just read the question again - you shouldn't be requesting pages this way.  I thought it was doing something on the page.  This doesn't work. You should use the routing or if you're using ui-router, you can use the state tree.

```
$state.go('mystate')
```

Comment: what do you mean by let is that an agular syntax

Comment: it's javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let